# Null value is returned from spring DI

Tags: spring

I am trying to read property file ,but value returned is null.

```
<bean id="propertylist" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="places">
            <list>
                <value>file:/myfile/configuration/myproject.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 


 <bean id="callManagement" class="com.callManagement" scope="session">       
            <property name="googlemapjs" value="${googlemap.js}"/>             
        </bean>
```

IF i replace  ${googlemap.js}  it with hardcode value . IT still gives null

NOTE::if i try to generate setter and getter using source>generate setter and getter it give "resource is not on the build path of java project".So i have to manually define setter and getters

Comment: please add more details on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:*.properties.default</value>
            <value>classpath*:${name of properties file}.properties
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And keep the properties file in src/main/config if you are using maven in your project

Comment: i have defined property file in config folder inside d>xyz folder

Comment: yes all the files inside all folders will be scanned as they will be present in the classpath